# bash merge files by matching columns

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I do have two files:

```
 File1

 12    abc
 34    cde
 42    dfg
 11    df
 9     e   


 File2

 23    abc
 24    gjr
 12    dfg
 8     df
```

I want to merge files column by column (if column 2 is the same) for the output like this:

```
  File1  File2
   12    23    abc
   42    12    dfg
   11    8     df
   34    NA    cde
   9     NA    e
   NA    24    gjr
```

How can I do this?

I tried it like this:

```
 cat File* >> tmp; sort tmp | uniq -c | awk '{print $2}' > column2; for i in
 $(cat column2); do grep -w "$i" File*
```

But this is where I am stuck...
Don't know how after greping I should combine files column by column & write NA where value is missing.

Hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: You could write `sort File* | uniq -c ...` without using `cat`.  It won't change the answer you get, but avoids creating an intermediate file that has to be removed.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since I was testing with `bash` 3.2 running as `sh` (which does not have process substitution as `sh`), I used two temporary files to get the data ready for use with `join`:

```
$ sort -k2b File2 > f2.sort
$ sort -k2b File1 > f1.sort
$ cat f1.sort
12    abc
34    cde
11    df
42    dfg
9     e  
$ cat f2.sort
23    abc
8     df
12    dfg
24    gjr
$ join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,2.1,0 -a 1 -a 2 -e NA f1.sort f2.sort
12 23 abc
34 NA cde
11 8 df
42 12 dfg
9 NA e
NA 24 gjr
$
```

With process substitution, you could write:

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,2.1,0 -a 1 -a 2 -e NA <(sort -k2b File1) <(sort -k2b File2)
```

If you want the data formatted differently, use `awk` to post-process the output:

```
$ join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,2.1,0 -a 1 -a 2 -e NA f1.sort f2.sort |
> awk '{ printf "%-5s %-5s %s\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
12    23    abc
34    NA    cde
11    8     df
42    12    dfg
9     NA    e
NA    24    gjr
$
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Can I ask what "b" in "sort -k2b" stands for?

Comment: You could look in the manual, of course...but it means leading blanks are ignored in the sort.  I omitted the `b` first time around, and join produce no data at all.  I'd encountered that problem before; I merely kicked myself and did the sorts again — rather than fret about what was wrong with the join options, which are excruciating to get right until you've done them a few times.

Comment: +1. speaking of join options, `-j 2` is equivalent to `-1 2 -2 2`. Also `column -t` can replace the awk command.

Comment: @glennjackman: The `-j` option is not part of [POSIX `join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html), but the `-1` and `-2` options are.  OTOH, `-j` has a long history (7th Edition UNIX™ used it, instead of `-1` and `-2`), so many versions of `join` support it.  In some cases, you might need to write `-j1 2 -j2 3` to join on the 2nd column of file 1 and the 3rd column of file 2; the POSIX notation would be `-1 2 -2 3`.  I'd not run across `column` as a command before; it isn't in POSIX, but is available in BSD (Mac OS X) and probably elsewhere.

Comment: Since posting this, I discovered that `bash` 3.2 does have process substitution, but only when it is run as `bash` and not as `sh`. I was running it as `sh` so it was not supporting the notation.