# bash: merging and sorting files

Tags: bash, sorting

For example i have 2 files

First.txt

```
John 5
Kate 3
Bob 1
```

Second.txt

```
Bob 4
John 3
Kate 2
```

And here I have no idea what to do, to create third file, which will look like that:

```
John 3 5
Kate 2 3
Bob 1 4
```

I'm trying to use 'awk', 'sort', but can't find a solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are the first two files assured to have the same names in them?

Comment: The POSIX [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) command is the classic way to do this. There are other questions that ask for the same — I know because I've provided some of the answers.  Possible duplicates include: [Bash script to find matching rows from multiple CSV files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17459789/) and [What is the simplest method to join columns from a variable number of files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18466662/) and [Bash merge files by matching columns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14517509/).  There are likely to be others too.

Comment: In those questions are just merging lines. I have to sort this values. I'll try to find there answer for that, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` utility can be useful here, but it expects the contents of the files to be sorted:

```
$ join <(sort first.txt) <(sort second.txt)
Bob 1 4
John 5 3
Kate 3 2
```

I know it's not exactly the same as your sample output, but perhaps good enough for your purpose?

**UPDATE**

So it seems you want to sort the values per line, so instead of `John 5 3` you'd like to see `John 3 5`, I guess. One way to do that:

```
join <(sort a) <(sort b) | awk '{ if ($2 < $3) print $0; else print $1, $3, $2 }'
```

Comment: I have to sort values not names, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

SF=""
SL=""
cat f.txt s.txt|sort|while read L; do
    #echo $L
    declare -a A=($L)
    if [ $SF == ${A[0]} ]; then
        echo $SL ${A[1]}
    else
        SF=${A[0]}
        SL=$L
    fi
done
```